# Select open terminal tabs to run command from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am trying to write a bash script in linux that opens two terminal tabs and then waits for the user to interact with the screen before running a command. From what I can tell, I am only able to run a command upon opening a new tab, but not after the tab has been opened. This is my example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mate-terminal --tab --title "left"
mate-terminal --tab --title "right"
read -p "Press enter to say hello"
mate-terminal --tab --title "left" -e "echo hello from left"
mate-terminal --tab --title "right" -e "echo hello from right"
```

I would like to be able to run these commands from the already open tabs but the commands after `read` open two more tabs. Is this possible? I also do not have to use `mate-terminal` if there is a shell that allows this use case.

Comment: You can certainly address specific terminals with `tmux` or GNU `screen`.

Comment: That said, I don't see why you need any kind of special terminal support here. "Waits for the user to interact with the screen before running a command" -- why can't you run a program that _does that_, and specify that program at terminal startup time? If you mean something in your old/original terminal is where the interaction -- well, you're the person writing the code, you can make the processes communicate through a FIFO, named pipe, message queue, or anything else you want.

Comment: (To be very clear, there's a sound technical reason why common terminals have mechanisms to specify what child process to run on window or tab creation but not later: Startup time is when they're _starting a child process_; everything past that, it's considered the child's responsibility to manage itself -- the terminal's job is to relay the child's output to the user, relay the user's input to the child, and otherwise stay out of the way; you couldn't implement the same interface between the two cases because only at startup time are you doing a fork+exec -- later you're just relaying input)

Comment: Please confirm this is not an assignment from a class. If it is, it's unclear what the learning goal is. If you're just experimenting that is fine, so , either way, good luck!

Comment: This is not an assignment from class.

Comment: Some terminals have an API (e.g. iTerm2 on macOS). Find one for linux or use tmux.